# tomcat8 IllegalArgumentException: The main resource set specified [/var/lib/tomcat8/app1/ROOT] is not valid

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat8

I have problem deploying two application on one tomcat 8 instance. I have app1 and app2. App2 gets up as intended but app1 isn't. Here is my `server.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!--
  Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
  contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
  this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
  The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
  (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
  the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
  limitations under the License.
-->
<!-- Note:  A "Server" is not itself a "Container", so you may not
     define subcomponents such as "Valves" at this level.
     Documentation at /docs/config/server.html
 -->
<Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener" />
  <!-- Security listener. Documentation at /docs/config/listeners.html
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityListener" />
  -->
  <!--APR library loader. Documentation at /docs/apr.html -->
  <!--
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener" SSLEngine="on" />
  -->
  <!-- Prevent memory leaks due to use of particular java/javax APIs-->
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.ThreadLocalLeakPreventionListener" />

  <!-- Global JNDI resources
       Documentation at /docs/jndi-resources-howto.html
  -->
  <GlobalNamingResources>
    <!-- Editable user database that can also be used by
         UserDatabaseRealm to authenticate users
    -->

    <Resource name="UserDatabase" auth="Container"
              type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"
              description="User database that can be updated and saved"
              factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory"
              pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" />
  </GlobalNamingResources>

  <!-- A "Service" is a collection of one or more "Connectors" that share
       a single "Container" Note:  A "Service" is not itself a "Container",
       so you may not define subcomponents such as "Valves" at this level.
       Documentation at /docs/config/service.html
   -->
  <Service name="app1">

    <!--The connectors can use a shared executor, you can define one or more named thread pools-->
    <!--
    <Executor name="tomcatThreadPool" namePrefix="catalina-exec-"
        maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="4"/>
    -->


    <!-- A "Connector" represents an endpoint by which requests are received
         and responses are returned. Documentation at :
         Java HTTP Connector: /docs/config/http.html (blocking & non-blocking)
         Java AJP  Connector: /docs/config/ajp.html
         APR (HTTP/AJP) Connector: /docs/apr.html
         Define a non-SSL HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8080
    -->
    <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               URIEncoding="UTF-8"
               redirectPort="8443" />
    <!-- A "Connector" using the shared thread pool-->
    <!--
    <Connector executor="tomcatThreadPool"
               port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" />
    -->
    <!-- Define a SSL HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8443
         This connector uses the NIO implementation that requires the JSSE
         style configuration. When using the APR/native implementation, the
         OpenSSL style configuration is required as described in the APR/native
         documentation -->
    <!--
    <Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
               maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https" secure="true"
               clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" />
    -->

    <!-- Define an AJP 1.3 Connector on port 8009 -->
    <!--
    <Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" />
    -->


    <!-- An Engine represents the entry point (within Catalina) that processes
         every request.  The Engine implementation for Tomcat stand alone
         analyzes the HTTP headers included with the request, and passes them
         on to the appropriate Host (virtual host).
         Documentation at /docs/config/engine.html -->

    <!-- You should set jvmRoute to support load-balancing via AJP ie :
    <Engine name="app1" defaultHost="localhost" jvmRoute="jvm1">
    -->
    <Engine name="app1" defaultHost="localhost">

      <!--For clustering, please take a look at documentation at:
          /docs/cluster-howto.html  (simple how to)
          /docs/config/cluster.html (reference documentation) -->
      <!--
      <Cluster className="org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.SimpleTcpCluster"/>
      -->

      <!-- Use the LockOutRealm to prevent attempts to guess user passwords
           via a brute-force attack -->
      <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">
        <!-- This Realm uses the UserDatabase configured in the global JNDI
             resources under the key "UserDatabase".  Any edits
             that are performed against this UserDatabase are immediately
             available for use by the Realm.  -->
        <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
               resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
   </Realm>

      <Host name="localhost"  appBase="app1"
            unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">

        <!-- SingleSignOn valve, share authentication between web applications
             Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html -->
        <!--
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SingleSignOn" />
        -->

        <!-- Access log processes all example.
             Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html
             Note: The pattern used is equivalent to using pattern="common" -->
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
               prefix="localhost_access_log" suffix=".txt"
               pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />

      </Host>
    </Engine>
  </Service>

  <Service name="app2">

    <!--The connectors can use a shared executor, you can define one or more named thread pools-->
    <!--
    <Executor name="tomcatThreadPool" namePrefix="catalina-exec-"
        maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="4"/>
    -->


    <!-- A "Connector" represents an endpoint by which requests are received
         and responses are returned. Documentation at :
         Java HTTP Connector: /docs/config/http.html (blocking & non-blocking)
         Java AJP  Connector: /docs/config/ajp.html
         APR (HTTP/AJP) Connector: /docs/apr.html
         Define a non-SSL HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8080
    -->
    <Connector port="8888" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               URIEncoding="UTF-8"
               redirectPort="8443" />
   <!-- A "Connector" using the shared thread pool-->
    <!--
    <Connector executor="tomcatThreadPool"
               port="8888" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" />
    -->
    <!-- Define a SSL HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8443
         This connector uses the NIO implementation that requires the JSSE
         style configuration. When using the APR/native implementation, the
         OpenSSL style configuration is required as described in the APR/native
         documentation -->
    <!--
    <Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
               maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https" secure="true"
               clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" />
    -->

    <!-- Define an AJP 1.3 Connector on port 8009 -->
    <!--
    <Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" />
    -->


    <!-- An Engine represents the entry point (within Catalina) that processes
         every request.  The Engine implementation for Tomcat stand alone
         analyzes the HTTP headers included with the request, and passes them
         on to the appropriate Host (virtual host).
         Documentation at /docs/config/engine.html -->

    <!-- You should set jvmRoute to support load-balancing via AJP ie :
    <Engine name="app2" defaultHost="localhost" jvmRoute="jvm2">
    -->
    <Engine name="app2" defaultHost="localhost">

      <!--For clustering, please take a look at documentation at:
          /docs/cluster-howto.html  (simple how to)
          /docs/config/cluster.html (reference documentation) -->
      <!--
      <Cluster className="org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.SimpleTcpCluster"/>
      -->

      <!-- Use the LockOutRealm to prevent attempts to guess user passwords
           via a brute-force attack -->
      <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">
        <!-- This Realm uses the UserDatabase configured in the global JNDI
             resources under the key "UserDatabase".  Any edits
             that are performed against this UserDatabase are immediately
             available for use by the Realm.  -->
        <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
               resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
      </Realm>

      <Host name="localhost"  appBase="app2"
            unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">

        <!-- SingleSignOn valve, share authentication between web applications
             Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html -->
        <!--
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SingleSignOn" />
        -->

        <!-- Access log processes all example.
             Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html
             Note: The pattern used is equivalent to using pattern="common" -->
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
               prefix="localhost_access_log" suffix=".txt"
               pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />

      </Host>
    </Engine>
  </Service>

</Server>
```

and here is `catalina.out`:

```
Nov 02, 2015 3:51:07 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile
WARNING: Problem with directory [/usr/share/tomcat8/common/classes], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], can
Read: [false]
Nov 02, 2015 3:51:07 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile
WARNING: Problem with directory [/usr/share/tomcat8/common], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [f
alse]
Nov 02, 2015 3:51:07 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile
WARNING: Problem with directory [/usr/share/tomcat8/server/classes], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], can
Read: [false]
Nov 02, 2015 3:51:07 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile
WARNING: Problem with directory [/usr/share/tomcat8/server], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [f
alse]
Nov 02, 2015 3:51:07 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile
WARNING: Problem with directory [/usr/share/tomcat8/shared/classes], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], can
Read: [false]
Nov 02, 2015 3:51:07 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile
WARNING: Problem with directory [/usr/share/tomcat8/shared], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [f
alse]
Nov 02, 2015 3:51:07 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server version: Apache Tomcat/8.0.14 (Debian)
Nov 02, 2015 3:51:07 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server built:   Sep 29 2014 11:26:22
Nov 02, 2015 3:51:07 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server number:  8.0.14.0
Nov 02, 2015 3:51:07 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Name:        Linux
Nov 02, 2015 3:51:07 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Version:     3.16.0-4-amd64
Nov 02, 2015 3:51:07 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Architecture:   amd64
Nov 02, 2015 3:51:07 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Version:    1.8.0_60-b27
Nov 02, 2015 3:51:07 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Vendor:     Oracle Corporation
Nov 02, 2015 3:51:08 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Nov 02, 2015 3:51:08 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
Nov 02, 2015 3:51:08 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8888"]
Nov 02, 2015 3:51:08 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
Nov 02, 2015 3:51:08 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 1064 ms
Nov 02, 2015 3:51:08 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service app1
Nov 02, 2015 3:51:08 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.14 (Debian)
Nov 02, 2015 3:51:08 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor /etc/tomcat8/app1/localhost/ROOT.xml
Nov 02, 2015 3:51:08 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase addChildInternal
SEVERE: ContainerBase.addChild: start:
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[app1].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:724)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:700)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:714)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:581)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1685)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot@31bb7338]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.resourcesStart(StandardContext.java:4900)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5029)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        ... 10 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The main resource set specified [/var/lib/tomcat8/app1/ROOT] is not valid
        at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.startInternal(StandardRoot.java:665)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        ... 13 more

Nov 02, 2015 3:51:08 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
SEVERE: Error deploying configuration descriptor /etc/tomcat8/app1/localhost/ROOT.xml
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[app1].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:727)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:700)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:714)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:581)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1685)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Nov 02, 2015 3:51:08 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deployment of configuration descriptor /etc/tomcat8/app1/localhost/ROOT.xml has finished in 97 ms
Nov 02, 2015 3:51:08 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Nov 02, 2015 3:51:08 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service app2
Nov 02, 2015 3:51:08 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.14 (Debian)
Nov 02, 2015 3:51:08 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor /etc/tomcat8/app2/localhost/ROOT.xml
```

The rest is log from app2 booting ok. I have set up context in `/var/lib/tomcat8/app1/localhost/ROOT.xml` which is merely:

```xml
<Context>
    <Resources>
        <PreResources className="org.apache.catalina.webresources.DirResourceSet"
        base="/var/lib/app1-resources" webAppMount="/WEB-INF/classes/config" />
    </Resources>
</Context>
```

I checked for permissions and ownership but it seems right, knowing that it is identical to that of a app2 which works fine. I copied ROOT.war and checked its checksum to make sure it didn't get corrupted on the way. I checked config xmls with xmllint for parsing errors but there were none. 
I think that this may be configuration error on my side but apart from the fact that app2 is working I've previously set up two apps on one tomcat8 instance and it worked ok.
Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I got this right. You need to chmod on the directory your ROOT.war is in so that tomcat can read and write there. I had done it on `app1_directory` but didn't do that on `app2_directory`.